# function to check if word matches search word

Tags: performance, c

I have the following which works but was wondering if there's a better way. Better meaning more efficient and or more compact.

The function checks a trie to see if the word is in the trie.

```
typedef struct nodeWords
{
    char * word;
    int    index;
    struct nodeWords *left;
    struct nodeWords *right;
} nodeWords;


nodeWords ** nodeArray;

/* nodeArray is a pointer to an array of pointers. nodeArray[nodeIdx] is
   a pointer to the middle nodeWords strut where word comes from a sorted 
   list. Basic divide and conquer routine. */

bool check(const char *word)
{        
    int nodeIdx = hash(word);     
    if (nodeIdx < 0)return false;       

    nodeWords * searchNode;    
    searchNode = nodeArray[nodeIdx];  //nodeArray is global    
    bool whileFlag = true, returnFlag = false;
    
    do
    {
        if (strcmp(word,searchNode->word) == 0 ) 
        {
            whileFlag = false;
            returnFlag = true;
        }
        else if (strcmp(word,searchNode->word) < 0 )
        {            
            if(searchNode->left == NULL)
            {
                whileFlag = false;
            }else{
                searchNode = searchNode->left;
            }
        }else{               
            if(searchNode->right == NULL)
            {                
                whileFlag = false;
            }else{
                searchNode = searchNode->right;
            }
        }
    }while (whileFlag);     
   
    return returnFlag;
}
```

for instance, we could rewrite the function this way:

```
bool check(const char *word)
{   
    int nodeIdx = hash(word);   
    if (nodeIdx < 0)return false;    

    nodeWords * searchNode; 
    searchNode = nodeArray[nodeIdx];    
    bool returnFlag = false;    

    do
    {
        if (strcmp(word,searchNode->word) == 0 )returnFlag = true;
        else if (strcmp(word,searchNode->word) < 0 && searchNode->left  != NULL) searchNode = searchNode->left;
        else if (strcmp(word,searchNode->word) > 0 && searchNode->right != NULL) searchNode = searchNode->right;
    }while (searchNode->left != NULL || searchNode->right != NULL || strcmp(word,searchNode->word) == 0);    
    
    return returnFlag;
}
```

I notice that the second function is actually not going to work as it's not quite the same as the first but we could change the while loop condition

Comment: The two versions presented are not equivalent. The first one does `free(searchNode)`, while the second does not. Please make up your mind. Besides, the question would greatly benefit if the definitions of `nodeWords`, `hash`, and an initialization of `nodeArray` are provided. As of now, expect downvotes and VTCs.

Comment: Without the surrounding code I can't begin to do a review, for instance it is not clear what the type of `searchNode` is. The fact that you delete it in the first version indicates it is a pointer but to what. To be able to do a proper view a reviewer needs to see all the declarations and how the `nodeArray` is built.This question is definitely missing code context.

Comment: question updated to reflect comments.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>I don't know C, my code is not tested.</sub>

- Having whitespace at the end of lines of code is really annoying to work with.
- I'm not a fan of `if` without curvy brackets. I have previously been bitten by adding another expression in the if and neglecting to add the brackets.
- I would much prefer using `break` over `while (whileFlag)`.
- I would much prefer using `return ...` over `returnFlag`.
- By changing the above we can change the `do while` loop to just a `while (true)` loop.
- If you've followed along with the changes we can see that `searchNode` will be null when we want to break from the loop. And so we can remove the inner ifs by moving them to the `while`.

```c
bool check(const char *word)
{
    int nodeIdx = hash(word);
    if (nodeIdx < 0)
    {
        return false;
    }

    nodeWords * searchNode;
    searchNode = nodeArray[nodeIdx];

    while (searchNode != NULL)
    {
        if (strcmp(word, searchNode->word) == 0 )
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if (strcmp(word, searchNode->word) < 0 )
        {
            searchNode = searchNode->left;
        }else{
            searchNode = searchNode->right;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```